# How to make container scale and the content sticks to the bottom of the container?

Tags: css

How to make container scale as screen gets smaller and that content sticks to the bottom of the container?

Height of content in the bottom of the container has to be flexible.

This is my try in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanur/w36p6pf0/1/. The problem in jsfiddle is that the container doesnt scale as screen gets smaller, and it should scale (by height and width).

```
    .grid {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150") no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}
.content {    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;      
    border: 1px solid red;
}

    <div class="grid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanxs.

Comment: are you trying to achieve this?: https://jsfiddle.net/e5ss2b25/

Comment: No, the content has to sticks to the bottom of the container. I edited question now.